# Formatted file paths in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I want to bind a folder to a docker container and I want to have the folder path formatted with the username of who is currently running the container. Here is my attempt at docker-compose.yml:

```
    services:
  web:
    image: my_image_file
    ports:
      - "8895:8895"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: C:\Users\${%USERNAME%}\my_folder_name
        target: /app/data
```

When I run docker-compose up, I get the error

```
Invalid interpolation format for "volumes" option in service "web": "C:\Users\${%USERNAME%}\my_folder_name"
```

Is there any way of doing what I want to achieve? I'm new to docker, so it might be that modifying the docker-compose file is not the best way to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Try using environment variables. I'm not sure what it is on windows for the username.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

I believe it is just

```
 type: bind
        source: C:\Users\${USERNAME}\my_folder_name
```